# returning dictionary to break recursive loop returns NoneType

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a recursive function where the input dictionary is updated

```
def update_dict(d: dict) -> dict:
    global counter
    print(f"COUNTER:{counter}")
    keys=['a','b']
    values=[1, 2]
    for k,v in zip(keys,values):
        d.update({k:v})
    print(d)
    counter+=1
    if counter==3:
        return d
    update_dict(d)
```

I want to return the updated dictionary after some termination counter, but get a NoneType:

```
counter = 0
my_dict = update_dict({})
print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
COUNTER:0
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
COUNTER:1
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
COUNTER:2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
None
```

Expected output:
`{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

Comment: you probably need to change your last line to `return update_dict(d)`.

Comment: A shorter version: `def update_dict(d): d.update(dict(zip('ab', [1,2]))); return d`

Answer (score -1):

```
    global counter
    print(f"COUNTER:{counter}")
    keys=['a','b']
    values=[1, 2]
    for k,v in zip(keys,values):
        d.update({k:v})
    print(d)
    counter+=1
    if counter==3:
        return d
    return update_dict(d)  # <--- fix is to add the return here
```